# How to set System Environment Variables from karate-config.js and read in java class

Tags: java, karate

I am setting the environment variable using karate-config.js if its null:

```
 if (!env) {
    env = 'sit';
  }
```

I am able to fetch env value in karate feature file, however my test case requirement is to pick the excel data based on environment

When I am using the below code to read the file name based on env, I am getting null as env

```
file= file.replace("RequestData.xlsx","RequestData-"+System.getProperty("env")+".xlsx");
```

Comment: if still stuck follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas : Really sorry the solution that suggested did not worked in my case as I want to set the environment variables at runtime which I am setting in karate-config.js and use it java custom java code.

Comment: I have only one extra comment. the system property name is `karate.env`. if that doesn't work, try passing parameters to java code from karate, there are plenty of examples if you search and read the docs